# What is the correct way of writing academic degrees and Professional license after the name?

Tags: degree

What is the correct way to write academic degrees after the name? The degrees are RN (registered nurse) MAN (Master of Arts in Nursing) MBA (Master in Business Administration) and DBA (Doctor in Business Administration

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion for those places in which there aren't firm conventions. If a single person held all those degrees, which cover two fields, I would just list the highest degree in each field, with doctorate(s) listed last. So

> Katherine Rose Arciga, MAN, DBA

Since MAN is less common than many others, further explanation might be needed in some contexts.

If you need to list them all, then listing in the order earned is one option (later, last), perhaps grouped by field. But, again, the it is useful to list the highest degree last.

If you are in a very formal place (Germany, Austria, Switzerland,...) then local conventions and, perhaps, even laws apply, so find out what the requirements are locally. A university might have someone to make that clear. The "Registrar" of records might help.

Professional licensing is a different matter. It might be good to list those before the degrees unless they can be assumed in the titles. So a licensed medical doctor might list M.D. before the advanced degrees if any.

Comment: In nursing, the *RN* is frequently listed with the degree as well.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, I think RN requires a license. In many places, it is a two year program, not a bachelors. So, yes, a bachelors in nursing is something beyond an RN.

Comment: Yes, that's why nurses often list both the license and the degree.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat country specific. In the UK there are a few commonly referenced conventions for post-nominal letters (first two require purchase):

[Titles and forms of address: A guide to correct use (2007). London: A. & C. Black.](https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/titles-and-forms-of-address-9781472924346/)

[Debrett's Letters After The Name](https://debretts.com/etiquettes/forms-of-address/)

[This guide](https://gazette.web.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/gazette/documents/media/calendar_style_guide_2018.pdf) is followed by Oxford University.

I have never compared these, but I suspect they are very similar.

Comment: Actually, it is _very_ country specific and laws apply in some places (Germany IIRC). The US is pretty informal.